# Errors while installing GraphQL

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, sequelize.js

I am trying to install GraphQL with sequelize and Graphql-yoga package but encountering the following error:[image]

Could anyone please help me fix this error. I am unable to understand what the error messages are trying to say. It's a Nodejs - express - sequelize - MySQL application.

Using Windows 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

`Graphql-sequelize` does not support version `^16` of `graphql` only up until version `^14`

[Graphql sequelize Package.json](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize/blob/master/package.json)

```bash
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
    "graphql": "^0.5.0 || ^0.6.0 || ^0.7.0 || ^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14",
    ...
  },
```